# Static node in Sprite kit scrolling background

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, sprite, swift4

I have a scrolling background in my sprite kit game. I am trying to make a static node in this background. I have already tried making it a child of my cameraNode but when I do it, it isn't visible on screen. If I just make the node a child of screen, It is visible but not static and scrolls off the screen. My code is below:

```
let lifeIndicator1 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: “Zombie3”)
lifeIndicator1.size = CGSize(width: frame.size.width / 12, height: frame.size.width / 12)
lifeIndicator1.position = CGPoint(x: frame.size.width / 2, y: frame.size.height / 1.2)
lifeIndicator1.zPosition = 150
```

when I do addChild(lifeIndicator1) it is visible on screen but scrolls off the screen when background scrolls.

When I do cameraNode.addChild(lifeIndicator1) it isn’t visible.

Please Help!!

Comment: No help as yet!!

Comment: Your question is poor, that is why nobody is answering.   It is broke on your camera because your anchor point on your camera is not the same as your scene, or you did not even bother to add the camera node to your scene.  It is broke on your scene because you are probably moving your camera, not the background node